# Were ordinary people aware of the US Constitution when it all started?

Tags: united-states, constitution

I read somewhere long ago that even ordinary people knew the content of the US Constitution well enough when it was adopted. Many people, not only rich and well-educated, knew what it was about. Now I want to find anything supporting this thesis for I collect data of establishing democratic governments. If you can throw me any link on this subject, I would be very grateful.

upd. I did only basic web search on the subject with queries like "United States Constitution a lot of people understood" and so on. I also read the Wiki article but there's no words about how the Constitution was understood in society. As I'm not a historian nor English speaker, I don't have and don't know any special literature.

Comment: Recommend [Pauline Maier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauline_Maier) on the constitution ..  The constitution emerged in part from the horror of the governing class at the consequences of the involvement of the common classes in the governance process.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace thank you for telling me where to search. I'll check out her works.

Comment: It is a fascinating question, but the research isn't obvious.  Maier is, I believe, the pre-eminent authority on the subject, and Wikipedia references/ list of publications should help tremendously.  If you have more specific questions, come back and ask again

Comment: Best place to start was in the history of the publication of The Federalist Papers, which were articles arguing for the new constitution.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, thank you, now I have plenty of material.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Thank you for Federalist papers too, I didn't know about them.

Comment: Mea culpa.  Never answer from memory. I should use/cite sources